# Vertical centering in bootstrap 3 container with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I have a header for a page, on the left side of it is a div, it's positioned on the left and is responsive using bootstrap 3.  I have an image, and then some text next to each other.  Because they're responsive they don't always center vertically in the containing div.  I tried centering them using jquery as follows:

```
var userImg_pos = function() {
    $(".lp-shell-head-user-img").css({
        marginTop: ($(".lp-shell-head-user-img").height() * ".5") * -1
    });
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $(".lp-shell-head-user-img").css({
            marginTop: ($(".lp-shell-head-user-img").height() * ".5") * -1
        });                
    });
}
userImg_pos();
```

but it doesn't seem to be working. I made a fiddle of the issue to show it. You can see on the left hand side the green square and the text, and that both of them are moved above their container half way, which doesn't make sense to me because in their css they both have top:50%.

Here is the fiddle, any insight on this would be appreciated: http://jsfiddle.net/cDz79/1/

Comment: https://github.com/PaulSpr/jQuery-Flex-Vertical-Center

Answer (score 1):

In order to position an element with `top: 50%` (or any other position), you must set `position: absolute;` in the CSS for that element itself and `position: relative;` in the CSS for the parent.

```
#imgparent {
    border:1px solid blue;
    position: relative;
}
.lp-shell-head-user-img {
    position: absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/7TXqg/